# generation of linear grammar

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

We have the following linear grammar:
$$E \rightarrow aO | bO | bbE | bb$$
$$O \rightarrow aE | bE | abaE | aba$$
Does the linear grammar generate a regular language, if yes why ?
Our alphabet is $\Sigma$ = {a,b} and our nonterminals are E and O. We begin by E.

Comment: Can you find a non-recursive way to describe $E$ as a set of words?

Comment: What do you mean non-recursive way?

Comment: Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar (which you already know) and think about how to convert your grammar into this format.

Comment: If you had read all the comments and answers to your prior questions, this would be trivial. You keep demonstrating that you are not interested in learning but only in having others solving your exercises.

Comment: [Exercise 6.1.a.ii](http://www.tks.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/teaching/ss12/th-inf-2#exercises), due May 31st.

Comment: @user1594 Try to express the language as a set. For example, the grammar $S \to \epsilon \mid a S b$ generates the set $\{a^nb^n \mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, this generates a regular language. We can show this fairly easily by constructing an equivalent regular grammar. We start with

$$E \rightarrow aO | bO | bbE | bb$$
$$O \rightarrow aE | bE | abaE | aba$$

Introduce new nonterminal symbols as follows:

$$V \rightarrow bE | b$$
$$W \rightarrow bX$$
$$X \rightarrow aE | a$$

Then we can rewrite the rules for $E$ and $O$ as

$$E \rightarrow aO | bO | bV$$
$$O \rightarrow aE | bE | aW$$

Now the rules for $E, O, V, W, X$ are such that (a) they produce the same language as the linear grammar and (b) they constitute a regular grammar. Since regular grammars produce regular languages, you're done. Also see the Wikipedia entry for Regular Grammars; a right-regular grammar is given above. To see that it generates the same language as the linear grammar, notice that $V, W, X$ can be eliminated via substitution to recover the original.

Comment: Huh. Did I make a mistake, or is the answer just silly?